# psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, sqlalchemy, tornado

We're developing a website which requires database access. Accessing such a page works fine; accessing multiple in a row is also fine. However, if you wait for a long amount of time (15 minutes seems to be enough), accessing another page will hang for a long time (10-20 minutes has been observed). Afterwards, [this error](https://pastebin.com/SkRZ7uQB) will print.

Here's the relevant code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
conf = load_conf(sys.argv[1])

engine = create_engine('postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' %
                       (conf['db']['user'], conf['db']['pw'], conf['db']['address'],
                        conf['db']['port'], conf['db']['database']), echo=False)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

app = make_app(session, conf)
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The database is on a different server. My personal machine is in the Netherlands, while the database is in a server in Germany. My partner's personal machine is in Italy.

Most notably, this issue is *only* present on my machine, running Arch Linux. We've tested this on two other machines, running Windows and some other Linux (I assume Ubuntu, can check if needed). At this point, we have no clue on how to continue debugging.

Of course, I will provide any extra needed information on request.

Comment: The connection has timed out. Catch the exception and create a new session then retry.

Comment: We could do that, however as I said it takes 10-20 minutes for the exception to even be raised, so it would not solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like something breaks your connection after a while. Check for firewalls!

Comment: Not using any firewall on my personal machine

Comment: The classic cause is a NAT. It doesn't have to be on your machine -- it could be anywhere between you and the server. Often VPNs, gateways, or other tunneling techniques use NAT. In recent years due to the IPv4 IP exhaustion, ISPs have started using carrier-grade NAT. Check your internet connection -- if you don't have a straight layer-2 routed connection to the server, a NAT could be at fault.

Comment: 15 minutes delay can come from the TCP exponential backoff mechanism with tcp_retries2 kernel parameter set to 15. You can check if the tcp connection is alive with netstat, and tcp_retiries2 parameter with cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2

Answer (score 13):

It's unclear where this 15-minute timeout is coming from, although as other commenters have indicated it's likely coming from something in the network between your computer and the server. However, wherever it is coming from, there are a couple of options to work around it in SQLAlchemy.

- The [`pool_pre_ping=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic) option will issue a simple test query before any attempt to reuse a connection, allowing it to detect this problem and reconnect transparently (at a small performance cost)
- The [`pool_recycle=600`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle) option tells sqlalchemy not to reuse a connection that has been idle for longer than 10 minutes. This is a more efficient solution to the problem since it doesn't add any new queries, but it requires you to work out the best recycle timeout to use.